# detailTextLabel is not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I know this issue was posted before, and i fixed my code according to their correction, but still not getting the detail of the cell working, only the main text. here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];//It's well initialized
}
cell.textLabel.text=[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"All the stores";

return cell;
}
```

What i am supposing to see, is a text and a detail text. However, i only see the main text. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the storyboard contains a prototype cell with the same reuse identifier, and it is configured to be a different style (i.e. to not have a subtitle). For effective debugging, you could remove the call for the tableview to give you a dequeued cell, and freshly instantiate one every time to see if your fresh cell is working. However, I recommend going the other way, and configuring a prototype cell in the storyboard, and using it's config (possibly even raising an exception if it is not present).

Comment: That's it, i had to change it from storyboard to Subtitle. It was set to custom. Thanx a lot :)

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm not using storyboard. any suggestion ?

Comment: If I create cell every time it works but if I reuse even with different cell identifier it doesn't works.

Comment: @RahulVyas Is there a cell with that reuse id in the storyboard? And is it of the appropriate cell type (one that has a detailTextLabel?

Comment: Also keep in mind that this question and response are 2 years old, and probably relate mostly to iOS 5/6... things may have changed.

Comment: @ctrahey I'm not using storyboard at all. I am using cell style subtitle. I am on iOS 7.0 sdk

Comment: @RahulVyas Best advice I have is to open a new question and post all the details, specifically the code you are using to instantiate and re-use your cells. Please post a link to your new question here so I can take a swing at helping!

Comment: @ctrahey I have posted a new question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904355/uitableviewcell-detailtextlabel-is-missing-in-default-implemetation