# UITableViewCell detailTextLabel is missing in default implemetation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

It seems a duplicate question to all of you but I have read all threads and I haven't found my answer yet so I decided to post a new question.

I am using default implementation of `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` but the `detailTextLabel` doesn't appear unless I create a new cell each time.

Here is the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [tblvUsersList registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return (self.registeredUser && self.registeredUser.count > 0)?self.registeredUser.count:0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if (self.registeredUser.count > indexPath.row) {

        AppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        if (self.currentViewType == ViewTypeUsers) {
            UserModal* user = [self.registeredUser objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = user.userName;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = user.email;
           // NSLog(@"Detail Text is %@",cell.detailTextLabel.text);
          //Console Prints Null here            
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: If you are using RegisterClass in ViewDidoad, you don't need use this:

if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
According WWDC 2012.

Comment: @Anton Doesn't solves my problem

Comment: It will not. But you have put all garbage code there

Answer (score 1):

try to change the line

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```